# Sorting a singly Linked List

Tags: c++, sorting, data-structures, linked-list

```
void NodeList::sortNodeAscending()
{
Node* swap = NULL;
Node* saveLink = NULL;


for(Node* firstPointer = head; firstPointer;firstPointer = firstPointer->next)
    for(Node* secondPointer = firstPointer->next; secondPointer;secondPointer = secondPointer->next)
    {
        if((secondPointer->studentId)<(firstPointer->studentId))
        {
            swap =firstPointer; 
            saveLink = secondPointer->next; 
            firstPointer = secondPointer; 
            secondPointer = swap; 

            firstPointer->next = secondPointer; 

            secondPointer->next = saveLink;


        }
    }
}
```

This is my code for sorting but the problem that i have is after sorting, all the values are correct but the head is not changed or sorted.

Output:
`{ 5, 0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 12, 15}`

All the elements are sorted except the first node.

Note: I have already checked the question in the link below and it is different from my question.  [Sorting a Singly Linked List With Pointers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19556427/sorting-a-singly-linked-list-with-pointers)

Comment: Look for the place where you assign a new value to `head`.

Comment: Use the debugger and a small set of numbers to find out where the `head` pointer gets changed.

Comment: i cannot change the head inside the loop because if i do the head will keep on changing until the last iteration, i just want to change it one time when i get the smalles value. That is the reason i used the two pointers to swap them but still save their values so that later i can connect the new swapped pointers.

Answer (score 0):

You are not updating head to point to the new start of the list.
At the end of the first iteration of the outer loop, firstPointer will point to the smallest element and can be updated to the new head.

Answer (score 0):

Sorting of **list** is not as easy as it appears in your code:

```
[prev1]   [first]   [next1] ... [prev2]   [second]   [next2]
```

should look like this upon swapping first with second:

```
[prev1]   [second]   [next1] ... [prev2]   [first]   [next2]
```

How to do that:

1. Store `next1` or `next2`, and keep track of `prev1` and `prev2` all the time as you **can't look back** in singly linked list.
2. `first->next = next2` and `second->next = next1`
3. `prev1->next = second` and `prev2->next = first`

During all this, you need to take special care for list's `head`.

Comment: Can you give an input which will be sorted in the wrong order (assuming the trivial fix of moving head is done)? I'll +1 if you have a counter-example, because I'm too lazy to check.

Comment: Yes, when `first->next=second`. Those things need to be taken care for sure. I just gave overview what all links could be possible.

Comment: That's not a counterexample.  A counterexample would be {5, 3, 1, 4, 2} which gives a sorted output of {5, 1, 3}. Darn you for making me write a test.

Comment: @SauravSahu - step 2 and 3 need to be reversed to handle the cases where the nodes to be swapped are adjacent and the case where they are not adjacent. The prev ->next pointers need to be swapped before then first and second  -> next pointers.

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out by Kenny Ostrom, even if the head issues are fixed, if the initial sequence of student id's is 5,3,1,4,2, then the sort ends up with 5,1,3, not sorted and losing two values.

The code is swapping firstPointer and secondPointer, which are used as the inner and outer loop variables. This creates a problem.

When swapping nodes in a linked list, the nodes may be adjacent (three next pointers rotated) or they may be non-adjacent (two pairs of next pointers swapped). To handle both cases with the same code, first swap whatever points to the two nodes to be swapped first (like swap prev1->next with prev2->next), then swap the two node's next pointers (like swap curr1->next with curr2->next).

Trying to use bubble sort or any swapping sort to sort a linked list is complicated because you need to keep track of two previous pointers to nodes as well as two current pointers to nodes.

It would be simpler to start off with an empty "sorted" list, then remove one node at a time from the original list, and insert the node into it's proper location into the "sorted" list. For this method, start off with Node * sorted = NULL; Once all nodes have been removed from the original list and inserted in order into "sorted", then set head = sorted, so that head points to the sorted list.

A much faster method to sort a linked list uses a small (25 to 32) array of pointers to nodes combined with a bottom up merge sort, but that is more than what is needed in this case.